# Redisplaying the results of an angular 2 component elsewhere in the DOM

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 component that makes db calls to render its results, like

```
<div class="row flex-items-xs-middle flex-items-xs-center" *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index">
   stuff here....
   <mydbresults [ref]="step._id"></mydbresults>
   more stuff here....
</div>
```

is a component that is being given an _id ref by my steps array in my parent class / component.   has an '@Input() ref which is used to make a REST call to pull some json and render it with its template.

This works fine and I get my results for each step.  Now I would like to show the collective set of  elsewhere in the DOM outside of the *ngFor loop.

```
<summary>
  all my db results here...
</summary>
```

I could write a component that essentially renders all the steps but since I already have fetched the results I would rather not have to make calls to the db again if I already have the results in my DOM elsewhere.

How can I re-render the results of all the  components rendered in the *ngFor elsewhere in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your `myDbResults` component output the result of the db call, e.g.

```
//Use this to output the result after your API call returned from the database.
@Output() 
private onDbResultFetched = new EventEmitter();
```

Have your parent component listen for this event, collect all the results and then pass it down via an input property to the `summary` component.

Optionally you could emit another event from the `myDbResults` component that signals the parent component that ALL of the API calls have been made, so that the parent component can only start processing the results once this is done.

If you also want to reuse the markup of the result, create a new component that is essentially a stateless component that takes the result of the API call as input and with the markup of your `myDbResults` component. Have `myDbResults` as well as `summary` use that component.

Comment: I don't want to bind just the results but the presentation as well.  So for example, if in component <mydbresults [ref]=1> the dynamically generated template has a result with formatting specific to that instance I want the dynamically generated component exactly as it is in the *ngFor loop.  Like mirroring the component called above, maybe by hooking to its id or something?

Comment: @code4cause You could create another component that is essentially the markup of your `<mdDbResults>` tag, but doesn't call any API's (so a stateless component).Then have your `myDbResults` and `summary` components use that component